# Ma'am: Is it as in "ham" solely for the Queen, whilst it remains spoken "ma"+"um" (less any glotal stop) for all others?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, received-pronunciation

It's become conventional wisdom that, when addressing the Queen after introduction, one must be sure to address her as "ma'am" as if it were to rhyme with "ham".  Only "ma'am" and "ham" don't rhyme.  Or they haven't done, not traditionally.  Well, save for in America, but one hardly imagines the Queen (or anyone else of the Estate really) wishes to be addressed as that travesty of elocution.  In fact, women in America are said to disfavor being addressed as such, perhaps pigs too if not for being dead, smoked, and biting an apple on their dining tables, but I digress.  Nevertheless of Americans, Britons certainly haven't traditionally rhymed these words, not even in RP.  Yet, here we are.  Because of some "movie" apparently.

In any instance, the question is this: Does "ma'am" as in "ham" apply generally speaking or only in reference to the Queen?  Has anyone stopped to consider that the pronunciation of "ma'am" remains as it always has been, with a rather tall "a" that slightly lingers sans glottal constriction into a rounded "um"?  That this "mam like ham" policy only applies, if it applies, when saying "ma'am" in reference to the Queen to the Queen* directly?

It is the Queen's English after all.  More especially, it is Her Majesty's pronoun to receive.  Presumably, One can have it pronounced at court as One wishes.  It's entirely her prerogative to ask to be called as she prefers, which is no different to anyone else really.  Frankly, she could very well order her staff to instruct her audience pronounce it "codfish".  Only, unlike with individuals of the general public making such a request, the Queen would likely be obliged, at least somewhat.  If it were indeed the case, it would perhaps be easier and less confusing addressing her as "codfish" than some permutation of the existing word "ma'am" which the people thusly presume applies generally and possibly shouldn't do.

Then again, perhaps it's the Queen's intent to "leave her mark", as it were: to prescribe a new pronunciation to this word most personal for her that will remain in indelible writ as legacy imparting.  Then again again, perhaps it's not the Queen at all, rather some uppity menial who enjoys messing visitors and dignitaries about as they are on their way to meet the Queen.  Personally, I blame the butler, but who knows?

No, really, who knows?  For I would like to.  With every basis for this pronunciation beating a path that leads straight back to Buckingham Palace and seemingly Queen Elizabeth II, it begs a question.

Comment: At least here in the US, when we say "*ma'am*" (a fading usage, but still somewhat common in the South when using the polite register), it *always* rhymes with *ham*. We never use *mum* (to us, that word means "to keep quiet" or "how British people pronounce *mom*").

Comment: *Ma'am* is usually /mɑ:m/ in British English. It was customarily pronounced /mæm/  or possibly /mʌm/ by those in household service (1800-1920 or thereabouts).

Comment: I often hear "mum" in BrE, never in AmE.

Comment: As a (republican) Brit, I agree.

Comment: @Dan: Americans do use *mum*. It's is short for *chrysanthemum*.

Comment: @PeterShor Pshaw, only in the plural (*mums*).

Comment: Another token Brit here - I say and hear "ma'am" rhymed with "marmalade" not "ham". "mam" rhyming with "ham" is more an Irish-derived version of "mum" in my experience.

Comment: Even though I am American, I would consider it shockingly disrespectful to call the Queen a ham, at least to her face.

Comment: We Brits write 'mum' where Americans write 'mom', but their pronunciation is remarkably similar, at least if you compare southern English with standard American.

Comment: On the U.S. chrysanthemum front, I fully concur with Peter Shor. It may be exclusively a Southern (or Texas) thing, but instead of referring to the pinnable flower presented to one's female prom date as a _corsage_, high-school kids called it a _mum_ (in the late 1960s/early 1970s, anyway), as in "Have you picked out a mum for your date yet?"

Comment: @DanBron - I have a friend from Texas who does pronounce it rhyming with *ham*...  But he says “Hey-uhm, and May-uhm”

Comment: @Sam How many Northerners do you know? 'Me mam' is a widespread term for one's mother up here (almost more so, I think, than in Ireland where 'mammy' seems to be common) and it rhymes perfectly with the word we use for salted pork and for anyone christened Pamela. I believe that the "ma'am rhymes with ham" instruction only really works for people with Public School accents.

Comment: "women in America are said to disfavor being addressed as such, perhaps pigs too" - How dare you. 'Ham' is the upper leg of a pig, not the whole animal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Debrett's recommends](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/royal-family/communicating-queen/how-address-queen) us to pronounce Ma'am to rhyme with *Pam*.

In my variety of British English, that is /Pæ:m/. My dialect exhibits the bad-lad split and "mam" has a long vowel. I pronounce *Pam*, *palm*, *cat*, and *mum* with four different vowels.

Update 28/04/2022 (the original page no longer exists)

> Use ‘Your Majesty’ for the first time and subsequently ‘Ma’am’. This should always rhyme with ‘lamb’. Pronunciation to rhyme with ‘palm’ has not been correct for some generations.
> [Debrett’s](https://debretts.com/royal-family/addressing-the-royal-family/)

I've never used the word ma'am in any context and I've never heard it used by any British-English speaker (except in historical films, or when imitating an American accent). Regardless of that, having either a word or a pronunciation that I would only use when addressing the Queen is not so strange: after all, I don't go around calling people "Your Majesty" left, right and centre.

Answer (score 1):

The first syllable of *madam* is *mad*, not *mard*, so why should *ma'am* not rhyme with *ham*?

The pronunciation *marm* exists, but is incorrect. (I was surprised to see that dictionaries describe *schoolmarm* as American, despite American English being rhotic.)

Comment: But you could compare *shall* with *shan't* where the latter has a different vowel in most forms of southern UK English (longer and further back) despite being a contraction of *shall not*

Comment: Thank you for my new word "rhotic."

Answer (score 0):

What you're hearing as "ham" should actually sound to an American more like "mum". The actual word being spoken, however, is truly just "ma'am". The proper etiquette, as it were, is to *first* address the Queen as "Your Majesty" and then, thereafter, as "ma'am".

This isn't especially unique to the Queen, by the by. The word "madam" has been historically used generally when people of a lower class speak with women of a higher class. For example, a merchant might historically have greeted a lord's wife as "My Lady" and then thereafter referred to her as "ma'am".

When referring to men, the equivalent word is "sir".

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. The question is: if you speak the standard variety of British English, do you use the pronunciation of *"ma'am"* that rhymes with *"ham"* for anybody ***other*** than a member of the British royal family? Or do you rhyme it with *"farm"* and *"palm"* otherwise?

Comment: The word is the word. How the word is pronounced will vary regionally. If that's truly the OP's question, it would be better suited for an online poll rather than a solicitation for the hard and fast "rule".

Comment: The protocol for meeting the Queen includes [instructions on how to pronounce ma'am,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madam#Formal_protocol) which proscribe what is probably the [most common British pronunciation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ma%27am).

Comment: That particular part of the article is descriptive, not prescriptive. Also, it's *prescribe*, not *proscribe*.

Comment: @R Mac: you should learn the difference between [prescribe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/prescribe) and [proscribe](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/proscribe). I meant *proscribe*. And if the Queen doesn't care how you pronounce *"ma'am"* why is it [recommended](http://www.debretts.com/forms-address/royal-family/communicating-queen/how-address-queen) that you should rhyme it with *"ham"*, a pronunciation that is unusual for many speakers of British English?

Comment: Ma’am is used as the equivalent of Sir in responding to a female officer in the American armed forces. (Not having served, I make no comment on pronunciation.)

Comment: Peter Shor has grasped the gist of my question precisely.

Comment: @PeterShor Not so. When I was at an all-boys primary school in the 1950s we called the female (married) teachers *mam* - rhyming with *ham*. (Had they been unmarried it would have been *miss*) From what we are told the Queen likes people to call her *mam* rhyming with *ham*, which seems to fit exactly with my experience of those days. What she doesn't like is *ma'am* rhyming with *farm*. And I don't blame her either. And incidentally *mum* (meaning mother) is pronounced differently around the UK. In the Midlands it is *mam*.

Answer (score 0):

To put it as plainly and simply as possible, the first time you address Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II you call her "Your Majesty", during the rest of any conversation you may be fortunate enough to have with, you are instructed to say "Ma'am" and yes that is to rhyme with jam/ham.

In the rest of the UK the following use of "Ma'am" structure is simple enough; If for example you were addressing a senior female in the police/military, even in military Air/Army/Sea cadets, you would address that senior female office as "Ma'am" to rhyme with palm/calm etc. And yes I used the word office because, she may not be an actual officer per se, it is used informally also to proffer respect to any female who is senior to you in any way. It is merely used to show respect and decorum also a way of allowing you to show respect without utilising the formal command structure. A similar example would be that of the Gunnery Sergeant in the US Military, they are often referred to just as "Gunny", now naturally you wouldn't call them "Gunny" in a formal or official setting but, it is widely accepted as the way to address them within the rank structure without the need to address them as Gunnery Sergeant 'Name' every time you speak to them.

As you can see following protocol isn't difficult, it is basic respect. Just the following of the laid down command structure, which has been built from years of accepted protocol being observed.

TL:DR It isn't difficult, first time you would address The Queen as "Your Majesty" following on from that you call her "Ma'am" to rhyme with Jam/Ham. If referring to someone else using "Ma'am" it is said to rhyme with palm/calm etc.

Comment: Palm rhymes with Mom for most speakers. Not for me, mind you, but for most.

Comment: @tchrist: Not for most speakers in the UK.